# как обмениваться файлами в чате WebSockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket

У меня есть чат на вебсокете, как отправить фото на сервер чтоб потом сервер перезаписал эту фото у себя и отправил ссылку на фото пользователем?
Ну суть задачи заключается в том, что пользователь должен выбрать фото своего профиля чтоб потом в чате все могли видеть его фото?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:
1. Делаете input типа файл
2. Считываете файл так

```
var reader  = new FileReader();
var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

3. reader.result - это то что вы отправите по ws
4. На сервер сохраняете как вам что надо, base64 у вас есть
PS Это не разу не готовое решение, но суть передал, в моем коде очень много чего не хватает